# Install a dependency using Electron on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, electron, sudo

I'm developing an Electron application, from which I need to install a dependency.
The package [sudo-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt) ended up partly working.
My code:

```
const sudo = require("sudo-prompt");
sudo.exec("apt-get install lib32gcc1", {name: "SteamCMD GUI"}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   // The code here doesn't execute, as it possibly waits for the user's confirmation to press Y and Enter 
});
```

And the dependency never gets installed.

How to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
const sudo = require("sudo-prompt");// The -y did the trick
sudo.exec("apt-get install lib32gcc1 -y", {name: "SteamCMD GUI"}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   // The code here doesn't execute, as it possibly waits for the user's confirmation to press Y and Enter 
});
```

The `-y` option makes `apt-get` skip the prompts.